# Update list item once library item is created

Tags: 2010, lookup-column

We have a list that is used to notify people that they need to create an item in a library.  We want to update a field in the list once the item in the library is created.  We tried to use the method in this link by setting the list as the child to the library (parent)

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-how-to-relational-lists-in-sharepoint-2010

but is seems to only work as we create items in the list, which does not accomplish what we want since the list items are created before the library items are created.  Ideally we would like to handle this without code, as it is always an uphill battle with our farm administrators to enable code within SharePoint.  So if this is done somehow in a workflow, or some other means that would be preferred.

Thanks

Comment: What type of item needs to be created? Would a workflow that creates the item for the user work?

Comment: Here is our current process.  We create list items of people that are notified to create an online profile we created in a library.  The workflow on the list emails each user giving instructions to go to the library and create a profile.  We would like to have the library set a field in the list once their profile is created so we know who still needs to create a profile and who does not.

Answer (score 0):

List should be the Parent and library should be the child. Parent Item ID should be filled in as part of user uploading documents. (This field can be a lookup)

Create a workflow on the library which updates the list field on Item Created event.

- Open the site in SharePoint Designer
- Click on Workflows
- From the ribbon click on the library
- Add action "Update Item in List"
- Select the list to update
- Add the field to update using "Add" button
- Use Fx button to set the proper condition

Comment: We will give that a shot. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: You can try to avoid having the user inform the value for the Lookup field by having the workflow find the Pending request based on the "Created By" field of the target list. Though this will only work if you can guarantee there won't be two Creation Requests for one User.

Comment: So we played with this and got the library workflow to successfully update the llist field, but about 10% of the time it causes a workflow error at the update list item action and stops the workflow....any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know the error text or code?